# Library to 'draw' binary trees in Python and Ruby

Tags: python, ruby, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to draw some binary trees in Python and Ruby and I was wondering if I can do it (in Python) with `Tkinter` or `SymPy`. 
In Ruby I have absolutely no idea on how to do it.

What I'm trying to do is to show it in a window or save it to a file, any of those would work.

I  can't find anything related and any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[GraphViz](http://www.graphviz.org/) produces some nice figures of graphs (see their [gallery](http://www.graphviz.org/gallery/)) and has a number of different ruby and python wrappers.

Comment: meh its pretty easy to just output dot language without a wrapper

Comment: @Jose_Sunstrider yes, that is one which I used. There are also others (google graphviz python).

Comment: BTW some modules that construct trees also know to dump tree objects in graphviz format, for example sklearn can dump decision trees this way.

Comment: I think I'll use this. Thank you very much!